# How to detect the number of grouped data based on their frequency

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers

```
 x <- c(1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,1,2,55,56,55,54,55,54,53,55,56,55,7,7,9,9,8,8,11,110,111,11,112,113,111,112,33)
```

if I plot x, `hist(x)`
The histogram shows that the data are grouped in 4 different groups.
[image]

How can I obtain that information without the need to plot the data? Is there a way to obtain the density of x and count the number of groups?

I tried to use the density() function but I couldn't find a way to count the groups of data. I think a way to count the number of peaks would work as well. Maybe it would be useful to be able to set a frequency threshold to define the group.

I would like something that would return the number of group, in this case 4 groups, or 3 if we set the frequency threshold to 5.

Comment: `rle(your_vector)` will be useful, provides lengths(of runs), and values(in the run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `hist()`, but does not generate the plot:

```r
x <- c(1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,1,2,55,
       56,55,54,55,54,53,55,56,55,
       7,7,9,9,8,8,11,110,111,11,
       112,113,111,112,33)
h <- hist(x, plot=FALSE)
newx <- cut(x, breaks=h$breaks, include.lowest=TRUE)
table(newx)
#> newx
#>    [0,20]   (20,40]   (40,60]   (60,80]  (80,100] (100,120] 
#>        20         1        10         0         0         6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: so  `tab_newx <- table(newx)`, `length(which(tab_newx >0))
[1] 4` gives groups. Is there a friendlier return object/approach than a table result? Just use `h` and let `hist` do the useful work.